# Run nodejs app through HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, port, os.js

I have a node app that is setup on SSH by running `node osjs run --hostname=dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org --port=4100`.

It starts at http://dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org:4100/ without problems, but instead I want to serve it through HTTPS https://dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org:4100/ , where I receive an error `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`.

If I use the port I'm unable to reach it with https, but https://dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org/ is accessible.

How can I serve the port 4100 through htttps?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `server.listen(4100)`?

Comment: Like this?

`<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org 
ProxyPass / http://https://dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org:4100/ 
Listen 4100
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation detail of OS.js. Their docs recommend setting up a reverse proxy for servers. Doing this will give you more control over SSL and ports, like you want

https://manual.os-js.org/installation/

Comment: Hi, yes I've been guiding through that link but I feel a little lost on how to apply the reverse-proxy to my situation:

`<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org 
ProxyPass / http://https://dc-619670cb94e6.vtxfactory.org:4100/ 
</VirtualHost>`

Should I add it like this to my httpd.conf file to enable it through https?